# Python3, pyqt5: NoneType error when setting value in radioButton connect

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have three radioButtons, which shall select preselect time intervals 1s 10s and any. I created the following connects, but I get the error message that argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

```
self.radioButton_1s.clicked.connect(self.setInterval(1))
self.radioButton_10s.clicked.connect(self.setInterval(10))
self.radioButton_any.clicked.connect(self.setInterval(0))
```

Doing an int-cast like self.setInterval(int(1)) doesn't make a difference.

The called method is the following. I know that the math isn't tight, but thats not the problem. Normaly the doubleSpinBox reads values like 0.25 0.1 or similar.

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def setInterval(self,i):

    if i == 1:
        n = 1/self.doubleSpinBox_TimeIndexStep.value() #TODO: use math.floor/ceiling to geht integers
        self.spinBox_CopyInterval.setEnabled
        self.spinBox_CopyInterval.setValue(n)
    elif i == 10:
        n = 10/self.doubleSpinBox_TimeIndexStep.value()
        self.spinBox_CopyInterval.setEnabled
        self.spinBox_CopyInterval.setValue(n)
```

What do I have to change to set the value right?

Comment: I don't work with pyqt, but I bet `connect` expects a function or callable. In which case you should be doing something like `self.radioButton_1s.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setInterval(1))` or maybe `self.radioButton_1s.clicked.connect(lambda *args: self.setInterval(1))`

Comment: self.radioButton_1s.clicked.connect(lambda *args: self.setInterval(1)) works great. Thank you. Could you please formulate it as an answer so I can rate it properly?

Comment: Ok. I didn't want to post an answer unless I knew it would actually be useful, which appears to now be the case :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connect` looks to me like your typical callback registration function. It expects to get a function or callable, but you're passing in the return value of `setInterval`, which is `None`.

If you want the radio button to call `setInterval` when it is selected, you need to create a function which will call `setInterval`, and pass that as the argument to `connect` instead. The shortest way to do that is with a lambda.

```
self.radioButton_1s.clicked.connect(lambda *args: self.setInterval(1))
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful. It upgraded my unterstanding of connects to that, that connets requiere a FUNCTION. I thought, that connect is just a trigger of the called method.